# How do you grant personal use access for Gmail's python API?

Tags: python, gmail-api

In the past, I was able to successfully follow Gmail's python [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) to gain read-only access to my gmail account. However, when trying to work through the steps today, I'm unable to authorize / grant access to the API? Specifically, I'm seeing this verification error:

[image]

Searching around, I found [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification?hl=en#personal-use) on not needing to verify personal use apps (which this is), but I'm not prompted with (or able to prompt) the unverified app screen. Are there specific steps I can/should follow to either (1) remove the need for verification, or (2) otherwise authorize access for my personal use w/o needing to go through the app-verification process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite about verification, the main problem is that your app is in "Testing" status.

Try to go to your GCP project's OAuth consent screen configuration page at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent. You'll probably see something like this:

[image]

Note the message about "Testing" status:

> While publishing status is set to "Testing", only test users are able to access the app. Allowed user cap prior to app verification is 100, and is counted over the entire lifetime of the app.

This means that in "Testing" status you have to explicitly add test users who are allowed to use your app. You can add your own account or accounts, or you can change the "Publishing status" to "Published". You will then be prompted to verify your app, but you can ignore it. The only downside is that you will be shown a scary screen saying that the app is not verified, but you can still bypass that to authorize it since you presumably do trust yourself.

##### References:

- [Further reading about the OAuth consent screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615)

Comment: Thanks! I thought about going down this path but then got confused as to what my "Test User" would be since it's just me? What would I submit as the user when I go to add myself / my desktop app?

Comment: Ah a follow-up: I just added my own email address as a user, and things seemed to work just fine!

Comment: That's great to hear. You can work with it that way, but do note that refresh tokens for apps in `Testing` expire in [7 days](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration). If you want a persistent refresh token you'll have to publish it and go through the warning screen.